# Recognizing Japanese handwriting and translating

Tags: translation, kanji, handwriting, video-games

I have found an old Japanese note that I would very much like to translate. Background info: I found it in an old gaming console where you're supposed to scan barcodes (barcode is at the back of the note) and it most probably has to do with that.

However, it's handwritten (and my Japanese is extremely rusty), therefore just recognizing the characters (especially the kanji) is very hard for me.

I have attached the photo of the note, and I am trying to transcribe it line by line. So far I have (and might still be very wrong):

1. 小 _ 生のじいちゃん (I believe じいちゃん means 'grandfather')
2. ( _ のう _ _ のみ木丑 _ の _ _ _ そ _ 土じろ )
3. _ いババ
4. (not even trying this one yet)

I was wondering if there are any tips on recognizing handwritten Japanese? Or if anyone could help me translate this?

[image: Japanese handwritten note]

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way. I'd be surprised if any OCR software did well on this. Learn Japanese well and get used to reading handwriting. Learn something about Japanese culture as well. You should know that 土じろ is not likely to be correct. It helps knowing that 悟空 is a character in 西遊記 and ドラゴンボール, too. And so on.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. Yes, you are very right about having to learn it. I am planning on starting all over again, I use to have a Japanese teacher, and with culture the language make so much more sense. This is at the moment simply out of my league.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it says

> 悟空のじいちゃん
> Goku's grandfather
>
> (そのラウンドのみ相手の必殺技を
> 封じる)
> (Blocks the opponent's special move in that round only)
>
> 占いババ
> Fortuneteller Baba
>
> (必殺技をつかっても一定時間BPがへらない
> (BP don't decrease for some fixed time, even if you use the special move

Comment: I was almost there.  Good job!

Comment: O wow, very well done! I would hve never guessed/known myself. I will most definitely need help with it as this is out of my league. But I will give it a try! Should I add in the question what I think it is and update it so I can be corrected?

Comment: Added a translation.